# How to get session timeout value through Grails code

Tags: grails, groovy, session-timeout

i want to know how i can get the session timeout value for my application

i have been set session timeout value in web.xml file and want to get this value through code like session.getSessionTimeout

if anybody knows pls post here

i just want 2 know that is it exactly set or not in web.xml for my grails application

Answer (score 5):

Try using `session.maxInactiveInterval`